# R - best way to sum categories stored as string, then reconvert to string?

Tags: r, data-structures

I have some data stored that includes a string column that looks a bit like a dictionary. The general form is repeating elements of "Category: Amount," e.g. "A: 1, B: 3, C: 10" etc.

In the whole table, it would look something like:

```
df <- data.frame(
    User = c("Bill", "Fred", "Bill", "John", "Fred"),
    Purchases = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5),
    Complaints = c(5, 4, 3, 2, 1),
    Data1 = c("A: 1, B: 2, C: 10", "A: 9, B: 10, C: 11", "A: 3, B: 0, C: 0", "A: 5, B: 8, C: 4", "A: 6, B: 6, C: 6"),
    Data2 = c("A: 1, B: 2, C: 3", "A: 1, B: 2, C: 3", "A: 1, B: 2, C: 3", "A: 1, B: 2, C: 3", "A: 1, B: 2, C: 3")
)
```

I want to find the sum of each column grouped by User, but for Data1 and Data2 the sums have to be grouped by the nested categories (A, B, and C). The desired result based on the above sample table would be:

```
summed_df <- data.frame(
    User = c("Bill", "Fred", "John"),
    Purchases = c(4, 7, 3),
    Complaints = c(8, 5, 3),
    Data1 = c("A: 4, B: 2, C: 10", "A: 15, B: 16, C: 17", "A: 5, B: 8, C: 4"),
    Date2 = c("A: 2, B: 4, C: 6", "A: 2, B: 4, C: 6", "A: 1, B: 2, C: 3")
)
```

I'm required to return the data in this string form. What would be the best way to structure the data in the string, perform the necessary calculations on all columns, and then return the calculated data into a single column?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a messy Base R solution I'm sure can be improved (but gets the result):

```
data.frame(do.call("rbind", lapply(split(df, df$User), function(x) {
  ro <-
    data.frame(do.call("cbind", lapply(x[, grepl("^Data", names(x))], function(y) {
      paste0(c("A:", "B:", "C:"),
             colSums(do.call(
               "rbind", lapply(strsplit(trimws(
                 gsub("\\D", " ", as.character(y)), "both"
               ), "\\s+"), as.numeric)
             )),
             collapse = ", ")
    })))
  
  return(cbind(aggregate(. ~ User, x[, !grepl("^Data", names(x))], sum), ro))
})),
row.names = NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

Doing this in two parts.

1. Sum `Purchases` and `Complaints` for each `User`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df1 <- df %>%
        group_by(User) %>%
        summarise(across(c(Purchases, Complaints), sum, na.rm = TRUE))
```

2. Do the manipulation on `data1` and `data2` and join with `df1`

```
df1 %>%
   left_join(df %>%
              select(-Purchases, -Complaints) %>%
              #Get data in long format
              pivot_longer(cols = starts_with('Data')) %>% 
              #split data on comma and get in separate rows
              separate_rows(value, sep = ',\\s*') %>%
              #split data on colon to get in separate columns
              separate(value, c('type', 'value'), sep = ":\\s*", 
                       convert = TRUE) %>%
              #For each use name and type sum the value
              group_by(User, name, type) %>%
              summarise(value = sum(value)) %>%
              #Combine the columns
              unite(value, type, value, sep = ":") %>%
              #Collapse the string
              summarise(value = toString(value)) %>%
              #Get data in wide format
              pivot_wider(), by = 'User')
```

This returns

```
#  User  Purchases Complaints Data1            Data2        
#  <chr>     <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>            <chr>        
#1 Bill          4          8 A:4, B:2, C:10   A:2, B:4, C:6
#2 Fred          7          5 A:15, B:16, C:17 A:2, B:4, C:6
#3 John          4          2 A:5, B:8, C:4    A:1, B:2, C:3
```

Answer (score 1):

The file more or less resemble a javascript object. ie `json`. The general format for json is `[{"A" : 1, "B" : 2, "C" : 10},{"A" : 2, "B" : 3, "C" : 30}]`. We can transform the string using regular expressions and the use `jsonlite::fromJSON`:

```
s <- function(x,fun = "sum", ...){
  fun <- match.fun(fun)
  x <- type.convert(x)
  if(is.numeric(x)) return(fun(x, ...))
  a <- sub("(.*)", "{ \\1 }", x) #introduce the curly braces.
  a <- gsub("([^ ]+)\\s*(?=:)", "\"\\1\"", a,perl = TRUE) # introduce the quotations ie " "
  a <- sprintf("[%s]", paste0(a, collapse = ",")) # collapse all the strings and intoduce the square brackets.
  
  #Now you have a json string.
  b <- try(jsonlite::fromJSON(a), silent = TRUE)
  if(inherits(b,"try-error")) return(fun(x, ...))
  paste(names(b), sapply(b,fun, ...), sep=" : ", collapse = ", ")
}


aggregate(.~User, df, s)
  User Purchases Complaints                  Data1               Data2
1 Bill         4          8   A : 4, B : 2, C : 10 A : 2, B : 4, C : 6
2 Fred         7          5 A : 15, B : 16, C : 17 A : 2, B : 4, C : 6
3 John         4          2    A : 5, B : 8, C : 4 A : 1, B : 2, C : 3

aggregate(.~User, df, s, fun = "mean")
  User Purchases Complaints                   Data1               Data2
1 Bill       2.0        4.0     A : 2, B : 1, C : 5 A : 1, B : 2, C : 3
2 Fred       3.5        2.5 A : 7.5, B : 8, C : 8.5 A : 1, B : 2, C : 3
3 John       4.0        2.0     A : 5, B : 8, C : 4 A : 1, B : 2, C : 3
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about `tidyverse` package (mainly [`dplyr`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/index.html) and [`tidyr`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/index.html))... Maybe it'll be possible with something like this:

1. separate `Data1` and `Data2` columns with [`separate()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate.html) or [`extract()`](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/extract.html), then
2. [`group_by()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/group_by.html) users, [`summarise_all()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/summarise_all.html) with `sum()`, and then
3. make one column again by [`mutate()`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate.html) with concatenating names and values by simple `paste0()`?

It depends on your real data, if you have all categories for all users (like `"A: 1, B: 2, C: 3"`) or if it happens that there is some category missing (like `"B: 2, C: 3"` with no `A`).

Answer (score 0):

A *base* solution, which assumes that the structure of `A: ?, B: ?, C: ?` is all the time given. First `split` by *User* than use `gsub` and removing everything not `0-9,`, then split using `read.table`, calculate the `colSums` and call `paste` to insert again `A: ?, B: ?, C: ?`. Finlay combine this with the result from `colSums` for the columns *Purchases* and *Complaints*:

```
cn <- c("Data1", "Data2")
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$User), function(x) {
  data.frame(t(colSums(x[c("Purchases", "Complaints")])),
             t(unlist(lapply(x[cn], function(y) paste(c("A:", "B:", "C:"),
 colSums(read.table(text=gsub("[^0-9,]", "", y), sep=",")), collapse = ", ")))))
}))
#     Purchases Complaints               Data1            Data2
#Bill         4          8   A: 4, B: 2, C: 10 A: 2, B: 4, C: 6
#Fred         7          5 A: 15, B: 16, C: 17 A: 2, B: 4, C: 6
#John         4          2    A: 5, B: 8, C: 4 A: 1, B: 2, C: 3
```